# Full Screen Fragment and Non Full Screen Fragment on Same Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have two fragments, A and B.

I want A to show on top of B (this is working fine, no problem here using a relative layout).

I also want to be able to slide Fragment A down to reveal fragment B. The kicker is that I want fragment A to show **on top of** the action bar. I'm using the new ActionBar compat library from Google.

How do I do this? I essentially want the opposite of action bar overlay (underlay?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I should have been thinking of this as a `DialogFragment` instead.

I turned Fragment A into a DialogFragment and added this to it's class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
}
```